# reading excel cell contents as Java InputStream

Tags: java, excel, inputstream

this code reads contents of cell of excel file into a string

```
String theCell_00=rs.getCell(j,i).getContents();
```

is there any method using which the contents of excel cell are read as Java InputStream

i need to read excel cell content and pass the contents to InputStream argument of this function

```
public void encrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out)
    {
        try
        {
            // Bytes written to out will be encrypted
            out = new CipherOutputStream(out, ecipher);

            // Read in the cleartext bytes and write to out to encrypt
            int numRead = 0;
            while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0)
            {
                out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
            }
            out.close();
        }
        catch (java.io.IOException e)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why? Which API are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always wrap the string in a ByteArrayInputStream and pass it to your function:

```
encrypt(new ByteArrayInputStream(theCell_00.getBytes()), outputStream)
```